# Click to show then when click another so hide it

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

When user clicked my `<input>`so will show some `<div>`

Then user clicked some another element agian like `<body>` or another div so hide it

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("div").fadeIn();
}).not(this).click(function(e){
    $("div").fadeOut();
});
```

Playground : http://jsfiddle.net/Zf34Q/

My code do `fadeIn()` & `fadeOut()` in same time :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQUery

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $("div").fadeIn();
}).blur(function(e){
    $("div").fadeOut();
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Zf34Q/1/

### Edit

Down voters, im sorry I didnt read the question properly, updated my answer now

Comment: Was wrong understanding ? :P But now your answer is correct :D , i forgot to use focus and blur

Comment: @l2aelba nothing, it was my mistake. Typical human, didn't read some words from your question

Comment: +1 Regarding the precise problem of OP, this is now a better answer than mine :)

Comment: One more question : 
 
If i dont use focus & blur , how can i do it with some filter element ? like click $(document) but not $(".mydiv, .mydiv2") ?

Comment: Remove the blur part and .. `$(document).not(".mydiv, .mydiv2").on('click', function(){...});`

Comment: i got alert when click `.my` too

Comment: hurray... http://jsfiddle.net/9Pj7N/3/ there should be better way to optimize this though

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("div").fadeIn();
    return false;
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $("div").fadeOut();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/rsSNw/)

The first callback returns false to avoid the event propagation to the document (which would launch the fadeOut). From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) :

> Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both
>   .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() on the event object.

**EDIT :** in OP's precise case, as the element is an input, it's best to use atif089's solution and the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function. I hope my answer at least helped clarify how to handle event propagation.

Comment: To avoid the event to be propagated to the document (which would apply the fadeout).

Comment: Its work, but any better trick ?. I try to dont call function all the time when click something

Comment: To stop propagation, so that the $(document).click is not called.

Comment: @l2aelba There's no problem in calling that function on evey click... javascript is very fast so that one call/click would not affect in any way the user experience.

Comment: in this case (with `<input>`) @atif089 is the best answer for me :D Thanks anyway @cristy @dystroy

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @atif089 answer, with the explanation of what was wrong with the original code:

The `this` when you are creating the selector is not the `input`, but some other object (probably `window`). If you wanted to make your `click` handler to trigger on any other element, you would have to bind it to every other element on the page, or use [delegate events](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events) on some common parent element.

@atif089's answer has a more pragmatic solution though, by taking advantage of the change of focus.

---

An example on how it could be done using `":not"`: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf34Q/2/

Comment: If i dont use `focus` & `blur` , how can i do it with some filter element ? like click `$(document)` but not `$(".mydiv, .mydiv2")` ?

Comment: @l2aelba When you use `$(document)`, it does not include the document's children, just the document itself. That's why the `.not` doesn't work. Take a look at the link about delegate events that I posted, it might make things a bit clearer.